# C# ext.net: (Workaround?) InvalidValueError: not an instance of `HTMLInputElement` (Google maps autocomplete)

Tags: c#, google-maps, autocomplete, ext.net

I am trying to use `Google Maps autocomplete` in `ext.Net` . I know that `Google autocomplete` supports only `window.HTMLInputElement(input tags)`. Is there any workaround that works?

**CODE**

*Javascript*

```
      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
          street_number: 'short_name',
          route: 'long_name',
          locality: 'long_name',
          administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
          country: 'long_name',
          postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
          // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
          // location types.
          autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
              /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
              { types: ['geocode'] });

          // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
          // fields in the form.
          autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
          // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

          for (var component in componentForm) {
              document.getElementById(component).value = '';
              document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
          }

          // Get each component of the address from the place details
          // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
          for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
              var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
              if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                  var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                  document.getElementById(component).value = val;
              }
          }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                  var geolocation = {
                      lat: position.coords.latitude,
                      lng: position.coords.longitude
                  };
                  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                      center: geolocation,
                      radius: position.coords.accuracy
                  });
                  autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
              });
          }
      }
```

Here are the 2 fields, if use the `<input` then it works, but if I use the `<ext:TextField` then it doesn't

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API_KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>

<td class="wideField" colspan="3">
            <%--<input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true">

            </input>--%>
            <ext:TextField ID="autocomplete" runat="server" EmptyText="Enter your address">
            <Listeners>
                <AfterRender Handler="
                    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
                      // location types.
                      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                          /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete-inputEl')),
                          { types: ['geocode'] });

                      // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
                      // fields in the form.
                      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
                    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete-inputEl');          
         var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);   
                                "
                    />
            </Listeners>
        </ext:TextField>

        </td>
```

Comment: what you trying to use instead input tag? TextField?

Comment: yes, <ext:TextField ...

Comment: @FabioBarros check edited post

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the TextField is the rendering timming, when you call your initialize function the input tag is not avaliable yet.

Initialize you autocomplete from the TextField AfterRender Event, like this:

EDIT: Sorry if i has not clear enough, you have to replace everything in the handler, i edited the sample. Also, remove the callback from the API call **&callback=initAutocomplete**

```
<ext:TextField ID="autocomplete" runat="server">
    <Listeners>
        <AfterRender Handler="
                autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                        (document.getElementById('autocomplete-inputEl')),
                        { types: ['geocode'] });            
                autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);                                                  
            ">
        </AfterRender>
    </Listeners>
</ext:TextField>
```

Comment: If I replace the commented line with initAutocomplete() I get this error: `Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined`, while I have loaded the correct API key and libraries=places